# Clear all Text Fields using a for loop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've used:

```
IBOutlet UITextField *text1, *text2;
```

for referring my textfields.

And I clear each one using:

```
[text1 setText:@""];
[text2 setText:@""];
```

If I wanted to clear all at once using a for loop, how should I write the code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should assign tag for each textField (say 1,2).

Then your code should be as follows:

```
for(int i=1; i<=2;i++)
{
    UITextField *tf=(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
    [tf setText:@""];
}
```

Comment: Thank you KingofBliss & Marcelo Cantos.

Comment: I think u r new to stackoverflow... If u think an answer is correct means u should click on the grey tick mark present left side of the answer.. U can accept only 1 ans

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use properties for the text fields you could do this:

```
for (int textFieldIndex = 0; textFieldIndex < textFieldCount; textFieldIndex++)
{
    NSString *textFieldName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text%i", textFieldIndex];
    UITextField *textField = [self performSelector(NSSelectorWithString(textFieldName))];
    [textField setText:@""];
}
```

To define a property:

```
@interface viewController : NSObject
{
    UITextField *_text1;
    ...
}

@property(readwrite, assign) IBOutlet UITextField *text1;
...

@end


@implementation
...
@synthesize text1 = _text1;
...
@end
```

You could name the ivar `text1` and just use  `@synthesize text1;` I use a prefix to avoid any accidental overriding of an instance ivar in a method. Also, you may want to use a `retain` instead of `assign`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (UIView *aSubview in self.subviews) {
    if ([aSubview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) 
        [(UITextField *)aSubview setText:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Header:

```
IBOutlet UITextField *text1, *text2;
NSArray *textFields;
```

Initialization:

```
textFields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: text1, text2, nil];
```

Setting empty text:

```
for(UITextField *text in textFields) {
  [text setText: @""];
}
```

Comment: a small change in ur code... for((UITextField *)text in textFields)

Comment: Thanks, I write it from top of my head :)